# Typescript type constraint inconsistency

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I am getting error "could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" when I have some code like this:

```
class BaseModel {
  hello() {
    return "HELLO";
  }
  static yada() {
    return "YADA";
  }
}

class OtherModel extends BaseModel {
  hola() { return "HOLA" }
}

class Factory<
  T extends typeof BaseModel,
  M extends BaseModel = T["prototype"]
> {
  private _modelClass: T;
  constructor(modelClass: T) {
    this._modelClass = modelClass;
  }
  build(): M {
    return new this._modelClass();
  }
  echoClassMethod() {
    console.log(this._modelClass.prototype.hello);
  }
}

new Factory(OtherModel).build();
```

However, if I change it to the following I get no error:

```
class Factory<
  T extends typeof BaseModel
> {
  private _modelClass: T;
  constructor(modelClass: T) {
    this._modelClass = modelClass;
  }
  build(): T["prototype"] {
    return new this._modelClass();
  }
  echoClassMethod() {
    console.log(this._modelClass.yada);
  }
}
// The following now gets the correct Intellisense for OtherModel.
new Factory(OtherModel).build();
```

If I use `InstanceType<T>` instead of `T["prototype"]` it doesn't work either.

Could someone explain why? What should I do differently so that we can alias type `T["prototype"]` in our function signatures for the `Factory` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you get this error you are using too many generic parameters. You don't need generic parameters that are themselves derived solely from one other generic parameter.

`M` in `M extends BaseModel = T["prototype"]` is not the same as `T["prototype"]`. If an interface `extends` another interface, that means that it meets the contract for that interface, but it also may have other fields. Typescript doesn't believe that it can guarantee that it can use `T` to create an `M` because `T` is only guaranteed to be a subset of `M` and not a whole `M`.

Removing the generic parameter fixes it because nothing extends anything else. The class you are instantiating matches `T['prototype']` exactly, because they are both derived directly from `T` and neither merely `extends T`.

Comment: In this case - is there no way to make it so that people don't have to type `T["prototype"]`?